# Power BI - Calculate Last 3 months AVG MTD

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a column sales in my model.

I would like to calculate the average of the sales of the last 3 months but month to date.

for example:

[image]

If  today is the 3rd of April I want the average of the sum of the sales until the 3rd day of the 3 previous months.

The same thing for the last 12 months.

Thank you!

Comment: and if its a 30 of march or 30 of apr

Comment: always the avg of the previous 3 months MTD